Exclude only PUT method from YARP routing
I have the following configuration for YARP:
"ReverseProxy": {
  "Routes": {
    "serviceA": {
      "ClusterId": "serviceA-cluster",
      "Match": {
        "Path": "serviceA/{**catch-all}"
      },
      "Transforms": [
        {
          "PathRemovePrefix": "/serviceA"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Clusters": {
    "serviceA-cluster": {
      "Destinations": {
        "Destination1": {
          "Address": "http://host:5000/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

For a PUT request on a specific route, I don't want to route via YARP, but use a controller in my API:
[HttpPut]
[Route("serviceA/api/action/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Update([FromRoute][Required] Guid id)
{
    ...
}

But I have the following problem: If I sent a GET request to serviceA/api/action, I receive a 405 error. I suspect the Controller is overwriting every method on the route. Is there a way to only overwrite one specific method on YARP? Such that GET request is routed via the proxy and a PUT request is routed via the Controller?
